# Dynamically Add condition to where clause in mysql query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, stored-functions

I have a Entity Table in which createdtime, modifiedtime, deleted so on... information is stored. id column in entity table will be the primary key for all module's related records id. Means

```
Table entity

 id   createtime   modifiedtime,   deleted,   owner_status
 1    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      0          0
 2    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      0          0
 3    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      0          1
 4    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      0          1
 5    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      1          0
 6    YYYY-MM-DD   YYYY-MM-DD      1          0
```

I want to add condition in query where clause "owner_status = 0"
Whenever select statement is execute on entity table anywhere in project.

Comment: Why do you want to do this entirely in MySQL? It is almost always easier to do this in the application you're running. In fact, if it is properly written, it will be very easy to do it there.

Comment: I think stored procedure or triggers may be used here.

Comment: Not triggers. [MySQL triggers activate only for changes made to tables by SQL statements.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) Since you're talking about `SELECT` you cannot use triggers. And I don't see how stored procedures could be used.

Comment: I want to do this entirely in MySQL b'cz there are lakhs of record in database and add feature when transfer record from one user to another user then that record owner_status  is set to 1.

Comment: Now Anywhere in project record whose owner_status is 1 will be excluded.

Comment: Please  help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you move rows, where owner_status is 1, to a different table? That way they are never included in any normal query, on the Entity Table, in your project.

Comment: No, this cannot be happened. deleted and owner_status record column will always handle in same table.

Comment: In my project, all queries already have  join with entity table will have hard coded where condition deleted = 0. Instead of  find all the queries of entity table to add another owner_status condition, i want some solution at mysql end which dynamically append owner_status condition if query contains entity table join.